# Getting an weird while following React tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following an Youtube tutorial for React.js project, and the tutor didnt face any error and I am facing one for exact same code, any help would be appreciated - [error after compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj1vo.png)
my react code - https://pastebin.com/htzES36G

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import items from './data'

const RoomContext = React.createContext();
//
class RoomProvider extends Component {
state={
    rooms:[],
    sortedRooms: [],
    featuredRooms: [],
    loading: true
};

componentDidMount(){
    let rooms = this.formatData(items);

}
    formatData(items) {
    let tempItems = items.map(item => {
     let id = item.sys.id
     let images = item.fields.items.map(image => image.fields.file.url);
     let room = {...item.fields, images, id};
     return room;

     });
     return tempItems;
}
render() {
    return <RoomContext.Provider value={{...this.state}}>
    {this.props.children}
    </RoomContext.Provider>
}
}

const RoomConsumer = RoomContext.Consumer;

export {RoomProvider, RoomConsumer, RoomContext};
```

please tell me if you need to take a look at other files

Comment: Please post the ```items``` from your data file.  That's where your issue is, you're trying to map over data that does not exist on that object.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington https://pastebin.com/Gy7KDQLL here goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're trying to access a field called `items` on the `fields` object, but it doesn't exist.  I think it's a simple typo and you're trying to access `images`, as that lines up with the data you're accessing.  I know it's easy to overlook things, but always doublecheck complex data types!

```
let images = item.fields.images.map(image => image.fields.file.url);
```